# Apache Proxy, which IP is used?

Tags: apache

I have this proxy setup in Apache

```
# Proxy specific settings
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off

<Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /solrsearch http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/select
ProxyPassReverse /solrsearch http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/select
```

My question is:

When somebody goes to `http://mydomain.com/solrsearch`

Which I.P would `http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/select` 'see'?

Would it see the I.P of the visitor.  Or since it is a proxy, would it see the I.P of apache?  (127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I turned access logging on in tomcat (the server I was attempting to proxy to)

The I.P was not 127.0.0.1 and it wasn't the client I.P

The I.P was

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

Comment: Same here. Is there any solution how to get the client IP when accessing tomcat via proxy? Ah, here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760283/apache-proxypass-how-to-preserve-original-ip-address