# Apache visitor actual ip for node application

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to use https://github.com/Zarel/Pokemon-Showdown. I have it working as far as it opens using a subdomain created using this .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sd.example.com
ProxyPass "/" localip
ProxyPassReverse "/" localip
</VirtualHost>
```

It opens and such, but the application uses user ip's.
But everyone's IP is 127.0.0.1. is there a way to fix this in the virtualhost?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache ProxyPass: how to preserve original IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760283/apache-proxypass-how-to-preserve-original-ip-address)

Comment: Not actually a duplicate but provides ways to get the original client IP

Comment: I've tried following the solutions there but I can't seem to get it to work? after trying them the application still sees my ip as 127.0.0.1